# No migration after running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

I created a model Book in book.rb.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I run `rails db:migrate`.
No error occurs.

In rails console I type `b = Book.new` but I get the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'books')`

When checking the migrations with `rails db:migrate:status` no book migration is found. Why not?

Comment: Can somebody please explain why he wants to close this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the model is not enough, you also need to create a migration that creates the book yourself.

In this case you should run `rails g migration CreateBooks` which will create the migration that adds the table. Then you can run `rails db:migrate` and your model will work the way it is supposed to.

More info on migrations: [Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: So it is recommended to create the book model by `rails generate model User` ?

Comment: Well, it saves the most work, so it makes a lot of sense to do it this way.